# trouble appending/combining two variables

Tags: html, css, forms, post

Here's my code, It's a forum, there are posts with dislike buttons,like buttons, and a text box for commenting with each individual post, check the screenshot below. I'm trying to put the $comments variable, which are the comments itself, at the end of $posts so it displays below the posts properly like the like buttons and comment box are displayed.

[image: here's the screenshot]

I'm trying to just get the comments displayed underneath the comment box. If I call displayComments(the function in $comments definition) in the for each loop then the comments get displayed separately from the posts I've tried combining the $comments at the end of $posts with this operator +, and I've tried making a new variable equal to the both of them. Here's the code(not the full file).

```
<?php 
include("connect.php"); 
include("check.php");
include("Trying.php");
include("Comment.php");

    if(isset($_POST['username'])){

                if (isset($_POST['post'])) {

                        if ($_FILES['postimg']['size'] == 0) 
                        {
                                $postbody = $_POST['postbody'];
                                $loggedInUserId = check::isLoggedIn();
                                if (strlen($postbody) > 160 || strlen($postbody) < 1) 
                                {
                                    die('Incorrect length!');
                                }

                                connect::query('INSERT INTO dry_posts VALUES (null, :postbody, NOW(),\'\',0,0)', array(':postbody'=>$postbody));


                        } 

                        }


                if (isset($_POST['comment'])) {

                    $postid = $_GET['postid'];
                    $commentbody = $_POST['commentbody'];
                    if (strlen($commentbody) > 160 || strlen($commentbody) < 1) {
                                die('Incorrect length!');
                        }

                            connect::query('INSERT INTO comments VALUES (null,:comment, NOW(), :postid)',array(':comment'=>$commentbody,':postid'=>$postid));
                        //}
                }

                $dbposts = connect::query('SELECT * FROM dry_posts ORDER BY id DESC');
                $posts = "";
                $comments = Comment::displayComments($p['id']);

                foreach($dbposts as $p){
                        if (!connect::query('SELECT post_id FROM dry_likes WHERE post_id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$p['id']))) {
                                $posts .="<img src='".$p['postimg']."'>".htmlspecialchars($p['body'])."
                                <form action='try.php?postid=".$p['id']."' method='post'>
                                        <input type='submit' name='like' value='Like'>
                                        <span>".$p['likes']." likes</span>
                                        <input type='submit' name='dislike' value='Dislike'>
                                        <span>".$p['dislikes']." dislikes</span>
                                </form>
                                <hr /></br />
                                ;
                                <form action='try.php?postid=".$p['id']."' method='post'>
                                <textarea name='commentbody' rows='3' cols='50'></textarea>
                                <input type='submit' name='comment' value='Comment'>
                                </form>
                                <hr /></br />
                                ";
                                //Comment::displayComments($p['id']);

                } 
                        else{
                                $posts .="<img src='".$p['postimg']."'>".htmlspecialchars($p['body'])."
                                <form action='try.php?postid=".$p['id']."' method='post'>
                                        <input type='submit' name='like' value='Like'>
                                        <span>".$p['likes']." likes</span>
                                        <input type='submit' name='dislike' value='Dislike'>
                                        <span>".$p['dislikes']." dislikes</span>
                                </form>
                                <hr /></br />
                                <form action='try.php?postid=".$p['id']."' method='post'>
                                <textarea name='commentbody' rows='3' cols='50'></textarea>
                                <input type='submit' name='comment' value='Comment'>
                                </form>
                                <hr /></br />
                                ";
                                //Comment::displayComments($p['id']);

                        } 

                }

?>

<form action='try.php' class = "forum" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <textarea name="postbody" rows="4" cols="60" class = "text"></textarea>
         <br />Upload an image:
        <input type="file" name="postimg">
        <input type="submit" name="post" value="Post">
</form>

<div class="posts">
        <?php echo $posts;

        ?>
</div>
```

Here's the function I'm calling in the $comments variable

```
public static function displayComments($postid)
        {

            $comments = connect::query('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id=:postid',array(':postid'=>$postid));
            foreach($comments as $comment)
            {
                 echo $comment['comment']."<hr />";
            }
        }
```

I know this won't help a lot of people but I'm just not sure what to do, How do you suggest I get everything to display inline, should rearrange my code?

Comment: It sounds more like you're looking for a CSS fix than a PHP fix?

Comment: this is not a PHP question

Comment: that's what it seems like but really I'm trying to find a way to put the $comments variable, which are the comments itself, at the end of $posts so it displays below the comment box properly

Comment: is there anything you would suggest though, like maybe moving around my code?

Comment: `$comments = Comment::displayComments($p['id']);` doesn't assign any value to the variable - because that method doesn't _return_ anything, it just pukes out its output right at the moment when it is called. Don't make functions/methods echo stuff - have them return it instead.

Comment: will try that CBroe